# Input values in one decision table should appear as drop down in another decision table

Tags: ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

I have a rules project where I need to setup some offers to be given to customers.

Requirement - The Business Users would be provided with a single Table like UI (which is a Decision Table), to configure offers.

The offers have various properties like - offer_id, offer_name, offer_expiration_date, offer_type (a $ dollar discount or cashback, etc), offer_group.

The conditions for which the offers were to be provided are around 10-15 and hence the decision table ended up being so large that the column names aren't visible, so we had to break the decision table into two. Now the business users setup the conditions of the offers in one Decision Table and configure the offer details in a different Decision table.

Decision Table1:

```
Customer Type | Customer Billing Amt     | Offer_Name 
Silver        |       $0 - $50           | Offer1
Gold          |       $51 - $100         | Offer2
```

Decision Table2:

```
Offer_Name | Offer_id | Offer_expiration_date | offer_type | offer_group
Offer1     |   Off_1  |  12-31-2019           | DOLLAR     | DISCOUNT
Offer2     |   Off_2  |  12-31-2030           | DOLLAR     | DISCOUNT
```

The business users have to manually type the Offer_name in both the decision tables,

I am looking for a way to have all the Offer_Name(s) come in a drop down in Decision Table1 from the Decision Table2. Like Say a business user configures an Offer3 in Decision Table3, when he goes and add the conditions in Decision Table1, in the action column, the promotion names should appear in a drop down. This way the user will not have type in the promotion name a second time and any typos will be avoided.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks,
AV

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Domain can be used here. You can create Offer_Name in dynamic domain (Similar to enum in JAVA) and then refer them in both decision table. Dynamic domain has an advantage of Constraint i.e only offers configured in Domain can be used in rules. So when new offer comes add  in Dynamic Domain first and then use them in rules.

Comment: We are using dynamic domains currently. Dynamic Domains would bring the same list of Offer names in the drop down in both the tables. For adding new offers, the dynamic domains needs to be updated. We were trying to give the business users the ability to configure offers from the decision tables view. Say if a business user adds a new offer (say Offer3) in Decision Table 2, and edits the Decision table 1, he is able to see the new Offer3 in the drop down list now.